# Velocity based on time rather than FPS

Tags: c++, c, math, physics

I'm making a simple application with an object that I apply gravity on..

I don't want the object to go too fast  / too slow when the fps rate changes, so I looked around for a way to do this and what I found was that I'll need to multiply the speed of the movement by the delta time..

So I decided to go for it but I ran into more problems than I expected..

On the game loop I have this:

```
gravityRate = 0.02;
velocity.y +=  gravityRate;
objectPosition.y -= velocity.y;
```

That's affected by the fps of the game of course.

I want the object to move 0.02 units per 16 ms,

So I tried to fix it like so:

```
velocity.y += (gravityRate * (delta * 1000.0) ) / (1000 / 60);
```

While delta * 1000 gives me the amount of milliseconds passed..

So far so good, it seemed to work alright and the object moved at the same speed even though on lower FPS it jumps larger gaps but that's fine.

The problem is that I would like the object to jump back up at certain occasions. such as collision or so,
I used to achieve that by simply doing something like so:
velocity.y = -0.05;

But now this doesn't work, well it does work but it's relying on fps again.
It jumps higher on higher FPS rates and lower on low FPS rates.
(I thought it could be because of multiple calls which gather and reduce the velocity more than expected, but it's not the case, it runs once only.)

I've been trying to solve it for a while but I keep getting more problems as I go.. so I'd really appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: This also depends on what you are using as the 3d/2d display, and what you are using to render it. That being said could you not pre-calculate the values for position/velocity/acceleration and then render a timeline based upon those values?

Comment: @Nomad101 I have a feeling that I'll get the same problem everywhere I'll go with this way of doing that, I have a feeling that in order to make it jump I need to change the way I do it, but I can't come up with an idea for that, and could you expand about the pre-calculations? I'm not sure I see where you're going with this

Comment: Ok so from what I have gathered you are trying to animate an object to simulate gravity. That being said the way you animate that object is highly dependant on how you are rendering it. As for pre-calculations, I mean you can create a map of where the object is based upon your gravity and any collisions you want to implement. Once the map is generated you can render based on this and you will get back exactly where it is supposed to be when it is supposed to be.

Comment: @Nomad101 Will this approach work for example in a game? for a player's movement? and about the rendering, all I do after this loop is render it from the renderer object I have, which simply draws the object on the final position I got from the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate both your velocity and position based on time like this:

```
deltaTime = currentTime - timeLastFrame    // time sins last frame
velocityDelta = deltaTime * gravityRate    // velocity change 

// calculate new position with only half of the velocity change this frame
objectPosition.y -= (velocity.y + (velocityDelta / 2)) * deltaTime   
velocity.y += velocityDelta
```

The scales needs to be adjusted to your game settings.

---

EDIT:

So in details - first we need to know how much time have happen since last:

```
deltaTime = currentTime - timeLastFrame    // time sins last frame
```

---

As the velocity keeps increasing with time, we need to calculate how much it have increased since last frame. The longer since last frame, the more the velocity is changed, those we multiply it with the delta time.

```
velocityDelta = deltaTime * gravityRate    // velocity change
```

---

In order to calculate how much the object have moved during the frame, the average velocity in that frame is calculated. This is equal to the initial velocity: `velocity.y` plus the end velocity: `velocity.y + velocityDelta`, divided by `2`. In short, this can be written as `(velocity.y + (velocityDelta / 2))`. With the average velocity we can then move the object by multiplying with the delta time of the frame:

```
objectPosition.y -= (velocity.y + (velocityDelta / 2)) * deltaTime
```

---

To be ready for the next frame we also need to update the velocity:

```
velocity.y += velocityDelta
```

Comment: I tried that, but I still have the same problem with the jump itself, on the same chance, may I ask what you're expecting delta to hold? because where I'm coding I don't have a ready made one so I basically save the time every time the loop runs, in milliseconds

Comment: I'm expecting delta to be the time since last frame.

Comment: If you want to do the jump back up, you should properbly do that on the `objectPosition.y` as well. This way it will always give the same amount independent of the frame rate.

Comment: If I'll do it on the objectPosition.y as well won't the obejct jump straight up rather than go up smoothly?

Comment: I have updated the answer to take into account that you keep increasing the velocity. This would allow you to decrease the velosity when you bump into something.

Comment: I tried to use this but it doesn't seem to work well either when the fps changes ;\

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it does work just great now but I'm trying to understand what it's doing and I don't understand lol, I wanted to achieve a similar result with normal player movement across the x axis but I can't seem to get the idea of this, is there a chance you could expand the explanation about it a little bit? thank you so much